# ClickOnce: File has a different computed hash than specified in the manifest

Tags: c#, clickonce, awesomium

I'm struggling with ClickOnce deployment and the hash checking in the manifest. The problem seems to be specifically with Awesomium, which is the browser control that I'm using.

I publish my application using VS2015, with "Sign the ClickOnce manifests" unchecked, "Sign the assembly" unchecked and "Enable ClickOnce security settings" unchecked.

I then obfuscate the .exe that is generated, and copy this into the Application Files directory. Given that I've done this, I understand that I need to update the manifests.

I then open up Developer Command Prompt, and run the commands as set out here: [How to use obfuscation for ClickOnce?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3416223/how-to-use-obfuscation-for-clickonce)

I'm doing this with a test certificate that I generated inside VS2015.

When I then upload these files to my website, it downloads all the files correctly upon running the *.application file. However, just before final installation, I get the different hash error, specifically with the Awesomium.Core.XML file. This file didn't change in my Application Files folder, and I would have expected the above commands to update the manifest with all the changed files in Application Files (After I copied in my new obfuscated .exe)?

How can I change my process so that this file's hash is calculated correctly?

Answer (score -2):

Try removing the default manifest for the assembly

[Check this](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vsnetsetup/2013/11/15/reference-in-the-manifest-does-not-match-the-identity-of-the-downloaded-assembly/)

Comment: When answering a question, please add a full answer to the post and only use links for "read more" purposes.